# Guess the name of their world

Tags: knowledge

The fish cannot swim and a bird cannot fly but a bird can swim and fish can't fly.

The world they live in is not real. The bird and fish both can understand humans yet they love to fight among them.

They live in a circular home but their earth is an oval shape just like ours.

It doesn't matter how hard you try you cannot find them in reality.

Hint:

> Children love them.

Hint 2:

> 'Bird' and 'fish' are specific to one breed (rather than all birds and fish in their world).

Hint 3:

> They can also live outside their circular home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These creatures live in:

> **Pokémon World**

*The fish cannot swim and a bird cannot fly but a bird can swim and fish can't fly.*

> **Magikarp** is a fish Pokémon which cannot swim (it can only splash).
>
>  **Doduo** is a flightless bird Pokémon which cannot fly.
>
>  There are, however, bird Pokémon that can swim, like the water-type **Psyduck**.  But there are no flying fish Pokémon (although **Gyarados** is part water-type *and* part flying-type in the early games).

*The world they live in is not real. The bird and fish both can understand humans yet they love to fight among them.*

> Pokémon and their world are fictional, spanning computer games, TV shows, movies and more. Pokémon can be trained by the human characters (and so can understand them) and are mainly used to battle each other.

*They live in a circular home but their earth is an oval shape just like ours.*

> The 'circular home' of a Pokémon is its spherical Pokéball.

*It doesn't matter how hard you try you cannot find them in reality.*

> They're not real, even though the augmented reality game Pokémon Go might make you think otherwise!